# Getting below error while building an image in docker

Tags: docker, aws, jenkins

Getting below error while building an image in docker:

```
 docker build -t demo .
```

Output :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : From tomcat:8
 ---> 8973f493aa0a
Step 2/3 : MAINTAINER "shweta"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4b846800a044
Step 3/3 : COPY ./webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Error :

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder389027616/webapp.war: no such file o r directory
```

DockerFile:

```
# Pull base image
From tomcat:8

# Maintainer
MAINTAINER "shweta"

# copy war file on to container
COPY ./webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always run `docker build` command from the directory where your `webapp.war` file is present.

`.` in `./webapp.war` tells the `docker build` command to look for the file in the current directory.

Without `webapp.war` in the current dir.

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

Output :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon    748kB
Step 1/3 : From tomcat:8
8: Pulling from library/tomcat
092586df9206: Pull complete 
ef599477fae0: Pull complete 
4530c6472b5d: Pull complete 
d34d61487075: Pull complete 
272f46008219: Pull complete 
12ff6ccfe7a6: Pull complete 
f26b99e1adb1: Pull complete 
21bec9c8ea28: Pull complete 
b8a32f28e27c: Pull complete 
94fdd0ba0430: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:bb4ceffaf5aa2eba6c3ee0db46d863c8b23b263cb547dec0942e757598fd0c24
Status: Downloaded newer image for tomcat:8
 ---> 8973f493aa0a
Step 2/3 : MAINTAINER "shweta"
 ---> Running in f84d33a29144
Removing intermediate container f84d33a29144
 ---> d1823a301759
Step 3/3 : COPY ./webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder241674033/webapp.war: no such file or directory
```

I created a `webapp.war` file in the current directory :

```
touch webapp.war
```

Now ran the `docker build` command :

```
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

Output :

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  749.1kB
Step 1/3 : From tomcat:8
 ---> 8973f493aa0a
Step 2/3 : MAINTAINER "shweta"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> d1823a301759
Step 3/3 : COPY ./webapp.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
 ---> 1f9c0af8b8d3
Successfully built 1f9c0af8b8d3
```

It built fine.